# where can I find the postreceive gear on openshfit?

Tags: openshift

My post receive hook simply runs `gear postreceive`. Where can I find this code and what it is doing?

There is nothing explaining this that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

The code is available in OpenShift Origin Github repository https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/efe69d24f4e7cb9941fb9932db8e6f3feebe6138/node/misc/bin/gear#L159. This primarily activates your deployment.

Comment: Where is this defined? `@container.post_receive` ? https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/efe69d24f4e7cb9941fb9932db8e6f3feebe6138/node/misc/bin/gear#L189

Comment: `def post_receive` https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/node/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/cartridge_actions.rb#L415